# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _GET

Tags: php, codeigniter, compiler-errors

> Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _GET in
>   /home/blunest/public_html/portal/application/models/Pagination_model.php
>   on line 62

The code on line 62 is

```
public function paginationInfo ($_GET,$numFound=0,$rows=ROWS) {
```

The complete function is

```
public function paginationInfo ($_GET,$numFound=0,$rows=ROWS) {
    $a = ' ';
    $currentPage=getVal($_GET,'start',0);
    if ($currentPage) {
        $page_of = (($currentPage) * (int)($rows));
        if ($page_of >= $numFound) {
            $page_of = $numFound;
        }
        $a.='<div id="paginationInfo" class=""> Showing '. ((($currentPage-1) * (int)($rows)) + 1) . ' to '. $page_of . ' of ' . $numFound . ' entries </div>';
    } else if ($numFound !== 0) {
        if ($rows >= $numFound) {
            $page_of = $numFound;
        } else {
            $page_of = $rows;
        }
        $a.='<div id="paginationInfo" class=""> Showing  1 to ' . $page_of . ' of ' . $numFound . ' entries </div>';
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Error Message!!

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Compile Error
>
> Message: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _GET
>
> Filename: models/Pagination_model.php
>
> Line Number: 62
>
> Backtrace:

Current PHP Version is **7.3**

Comment: You cannot use Super Global variable  as a parameter since PHP 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `$_GET` from the function parameter as it's already declared as GLOBAL variable and you are again declaring it for a function. If you want to access it, just access it without the need of sending it as parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can think `$_GET` as a reserved keyword, so it cannot be used as an argument.( You can just remove that argument )